# Как взломать bootloader?

Tags: android, ассемблер, arm, взлом, root

Дело в том, что мне нужны рут права, а для этого нужно разблокировать bootloader. Проблема заключается в том, что при выборе в меню его открытия, запускается вечный fastboot mode, который не реагирует ни на что, кроме как вытаскивания батареи.
По этому я и решил, что нужно попытаться поработать с прошивкой самому (LG K7 X230)
Ссыль на прошивку - https://4pda.ru/pages/go/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fyadi.sk%2Fd%2FE7HdIHX43W8eAx&e=88689907

Какое то время я осваивал ассемблер, читал нужную литературу, осваивал деббагеры (ollydebug, IDA pro), ломал и создавал маленькие программки,но так и не понял что нужно сделать, что бы всё таки хоть что то сделать с прошивкой.
И да, на 4pda есть инструкция по этому делу, но для меня она всё ещё в основном не понятна, так как в ней нет конкретики.
И в общем, у меня появилась просьба, пожалуйста, распишите мне подробно каждый шаг, что нужно сделать, что бы всё таки понять, как и что нужно изменить в прошивке, что бы восстановить возможность открыть bootloader?

Ps.
Обращался за выдачей рута, и вопросами по этой теме в поддержку LG, но ничего кроме как - "Это не предусмотрено производителем" мне не сказали.

Comment: Независимо от ассемблеров в устройстве скорее всего стоит куча проверок цифровых подписей кода, и модифицированный код просто откажется запускаться, а значит придётся выпаивать память из платы и каким-нибудь программатором отключать проверку цифровой подписи (если соответствующий участок памяти вообще возможно перезаписать)

Comment: Советую обратиться на какие нибудь рынки с электроникой, там много специалистов                         P.S сам на "Горбушкин двор"в москве отдавал и мне там рут поставили